# Lambda Apply on Pandas values taking the average of row before and after

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I have a price time-series where I wish cleanse the data-set. How I plan to do it is to set 'incorrect' jump in prices to the average of the 'before' and 'after' price.

I have a panda frame name df, with price as 'mid'. I set the prx_chg as per below.

```
df['prx_chg'] = df['mid'].pct_change(periods= 1, fill_method='pad', limit=None, freq=None).shift(periods = -1).fillna(0)
```

Is there a simple way, to set across the rows of 'mid' such that if the prx_chg is above a magnitude X, the 'mid' is set to be the average of [row -1], [row +1] ?

I tried the below using lambda apply, but didn't work

```
mid = [1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 100, 1.2, 0.9, -100, 1.2]
df = pd.DataFrame(mid, columns = ['mid'])
df['prx_chg'] = df['mid'].pct_change(periods= 1, fill_method='pad', limit=None, freq=None).shift(periods = -1).fillna(0)

df.apply(lambda row: row['mid'] = np.average(a, b) if row['prx_chg'] >= n.abs(10))
```

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you might use `np.where` and `shift` in this case;

```
df['mid'] = np.where((df['prx_chg'].shift(1) >= 10) | (df['prx_chg'].shift(1) <= -10), (df['mid'].shift(-1) + df['mid'].shift(1)) / 2, df['mid'])

df

    mid     prx_chg
0  1.00    0.100000
1  1.10   -0.090909
2  1.00   99.000000
3  1.10   -0.988000
4  1.20   -0.250000
5  0.90 -112.111111
6  1.05   -1.012000
7  1.20    0.000000
```